# Can not get LESS Recursive Loop working correctly with variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

When I try to compile the LESS code below, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'numerator' of undefined in
```

I have tried all different kinds of combinations, but still unable to compile the LESS. What am I doing wrong? Thank you, any kind of direction would be helpful.

```
.generate-heights(@total, @unit, @count: 1) when (@count =< @total) {
    .@{unit}-@{count}{
        height: @total + @unit;
    }
    .generate-heights(@total, @unit, (@count + 1));
}

.generate-heights(100, vh);
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match with the code provided. The other problem in your code is that `+` in Less is not used for String concatenation. `height: @total + @unit;` will definitely give an error and I think what you need is `height: unit(@total, @unit)`.

Comment: '@total is suppose to be @count', so that was one error. Thank you very much, I was looking through the docs trying to find something like this, did not get to the Misc Functions on the site yet. Thank you again!